# QWebEngineView works on Windows but grey blank Page on OSX in Pyside2

Tags: python, maya, pyside2, qtwebengine

I have created a simple example, which shows that running the same code in Windows works as expected but on OSX it shows a dark grey page. Any Ideas?

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineView

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webEngineView)
        initialUrl = "https://www.google.com"


        self.webEngineView.load(QUrl(initialUrl))
        self.webEngineView.load(initialUrl)


mainWin = MainWindow()
mainWin.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What version of pyside2 do you use? Try updating it: `python -m pip install --upgrade pyside2`

Comment: This is shipped with Autodesk Maya (Python2)

Comment: mmm, maybe maya is causing the error.

Comment: Try resizing the window, that forces it to render.

Answer (score 0):

The following code **works fine** in `Autodesk Maya 2020` in `macOS 10.15.5 Catalina`:

So if it doesn't work as expected in Windows you need to upgrade your `PySide2` libs!

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):   

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webEngineView)
        initialUrl = "https://www.autodesk.com"

        self.webEngineView.load(QUrl(initialUrl))
        self.webEngineView.load(initialUrl)
            
mainWin = MainWindow()
mainWin.show()
```

[image]

P.S.

If you're still experiencing this issue reinstall Maya from scratch.

Comment: You are running this from Maya's script editor and it launches perfectly fine?

Comment: Yes, I launched it from Script Editor (Maya student version).

Comment: That is weird, I mean I did use the student version too and PySide2 is pointing to `/Applications/Autodesk/maya2019/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide2/__init__.pyc # ` For some reason that window is always grey for me.

Comment: Then delete all Maya folders and install it from scratch.

Comment: I've tested this now on multiple mac's with Catalina 10.15.12, it's always a grey page.

Comment: You probably mean 10.15.2, not 10.15.12 ? Then update your OS till 10.15.6. Seems that it's a system's bug.